# joint density formula of i.i.d. exponential random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> Let $X_1 , X_2 , ...., X_n$ be a set of independent and identically
>   distributed exponential random variables. Find the joint density
>   function formula $f (x_1, x_2, ...., x_n)$, simplifying as much as
>   possible.

Why is the answer $$\lambda^n(e^{-\lambda\sum_{i=0}^n X_i})$$ instead of just $$\lambda^n(e^{-n\lambda X})$$

Comment: You have $n-$dim. random vector $(X_1,...,X_n)$, so it's density function (if it exists of course) has to be an $n-$variable function. In your case $f(x_1,...,x_n) = \lambda^n \cdot e^{-\lambda \sum_{k=1}^n x_k }$ (on set $[0,+\infty)^n$), $0$ otherwise

Comment: that makes sense. I was was thinking that because each variable is identical, that their pdfs would all be the same and we could just multiply them together

Comment: Yes, they are the same, and you indeed multiply them (due to variables being independent), but you must be careful, cause each random variable in your vector has its own variable in the joint pdf

Comment: Another problem asks for P(x1 > 4,x2 > 4,......,x10 > 4). So pretty much the probability that all ten r.v. are greater than 4. I thought we could use the joint pdf (using the second equation in my question) for this with n = 10 and the given lambda and I would get the answer but this is not the case. I would have to take (1 - (P < 4))^10 to get the answer. Why is this? Sorry if this question is too long for the comment sectioncand thank you for your time.

Comment: $ \mathbb P(X_1 >4,...,X_{10} >4) = \int_{(4,+\infty)^{10}} f(x_1,...,x_{10})d\lambda_{10}(x_1,...,x_{10}) = (\lambda \int_4^{\infty} e^{-\lambda\cdot x} dx )^{10} = (e^{-4\lambda})^{10} = e^{-40\lambda}$

Comment: Thank you for your clear and concise explanations!

Answer (score 1):

The random variables are iid; therefore,

\begin{align*} f_{X_1 \dots X_n}(x_1,\dots,x_n | \lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^n
 f_{X_i}(x_i | \lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda e^{-\lambda x} = \lambda^n \prod_{i=1}^n e^{-\lambda x} = \lambda^n e^{-\lambda \sum_{i=1}^n x_i}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).